# Dating when parent died

Tags: mourning-aveilus, shidduchim-dating

What are the laws/customs of dating/shiddichim during the first 30 days or the first year after a parent died?

What if it happened to the one you are(or want to) date/ing?

Comment: Although this does not get into all possible specifics of your question it is a good outline to learn from. [about mourning](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/281640/jewish/Joyous-Occasions-During-Mourning.htm)

Comment: @DavidKenner thank you, from there I can deduce that after the first 30 days is like regular